# How can I prevent empty input?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code, and if I click **send** it send with empty fields... Can i prevent this? ex: if user submit with empty fields, will appear one alert..

```
<!-- Author: Michael Milstead / Mode87.com
     for Untame.net
     Twitter Bootstrap Tutorial
     Modal Contact Demo, 2013
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Twitter Bootstrap Modal Contact Form Demo</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Creating Modal Window with Twitter Bootstrap">

    <link href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input#submit").click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php", // 
                    data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#thanks").html(msg)
                        $("#form-content").modal('hide');   
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body { margin: 50px; background: url(assets/bglight.png); }
        .well { background: #fff; text-align: center; }
        .modal { text-align: left; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="well well-large">
        <h2>Twitter Bootstrap Modal Contact Form Demo</h2>
        <div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                <h3>Send me a message</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="contact" name="contact">
                    <label class="label" for="name" required>Your Name</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="input-xlarge"><br>
                    <label class="label" for="email">Your E-mail</label><br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="input-xlarge"><br>
                    <label class="label" for="message">Enter a Message</label><br>
                    <textarea name="message" class="input-xlarge"></textarea>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send!" id="submit">
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Nah.</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="thanks"><p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#form-content" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Modal powers, activate!</a></p></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried some ways to do this but i cant, i used `ev.preventDefault();` but then the button `send` didn't work :ss

Answer (score 0):

For your send method, use return true and return false.

```
$("input#submit").click(function(){
If(userInputs === null){
    Alert("please fill out form");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php", // 
                data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#thanks").html(msg)
                    $("#form-content").modal('hide');   
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't work, the button dont work.. If I have empty fields or not :(

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault();` after your click handler / event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `required` attribute for any input elements that can't be empty:

```
 <input type="text" name="name" required />
```

Since you are trying to send the form over ajax, you should do something like:

```
var emptyRequired $('[required]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val()==='';
});

if (emptyRequired) return true;
```

That way, the submit event returns to the browser, which will then handle the empty `required` input natively, but otherwise it moves on to the ajax call.

Comment: I used before and didn't result.. When I submit, didn't appeared me any "stop" message  by `required`

Comment: It should halt the submit and show some flag on the required field. Make sure any js event handlers aren't breaking this, and that your browser is compatible with this newer attribute : http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html

Comment: Oh I see, you're not actually submitting the form, you're serializing it and sending it via AJAX. You'll want to add something to the event listener that checks that all required fields have a value. Maybe return `true` instead of the ajax function, so that browser receives `submit` event and handles the required fields directly.

Comment: Can u help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a form validator plugin?
there are plenty of that you can find on google or you can do it easily by yourself.